# Anyone know where I can download a copy of Sun Java System Active Server Pages 4.0.3 for Solaris

Tags: solaris, asp, pci-dss, sun-one

I've contacted Sun regarding this and they have told me that the download is no longer available as Active Server Pages 4.0.3 is now End Of Life. We need to upgrade our server to 4.0.3 to acheive PCI-DSS compliance.

Anyone know of a site where I can download older copies of Sun files? Sun offer 4.0.1 and 4.0.2 to download but not 4.0.3 which is going to cause problems come October when Visa stops accepting transactions from non PCI compliant servers.

If Sun kept their naming system consistent across versions, the file would be called "sjsasp403-sol-sparc.tar". I know the real solution is to upgrade every site on the server to use a different server language, i.e. PHP, and in the long term, this is our goal but we have over 100 sites requiring upgrading and its not a viable solution to get this done before October.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to source a copy of the download off a contact of mine. If anyone needs it, get in touch via my personal site.

Answer (score 1):

Google found this: [4.0.3 Download](http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/prod/sjs.asp403?l=en&a=view) when I searched for

> sun active server pages  4.0.3 download

HTH

Comment: that's just the zipped documentation for it. cheers tho. i spoke to a guy at sun today and if i can get a copy, i'll let people know how if needed.